# Set createDrawerNavigator screen title react native

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have below codebase

```
const drNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {

    A: {
      screen: A,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'A',
      },
    },
    B: {
      screen: B,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'B',
      },
    },
    C: {
      screen: C,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'C',
      },
    },
    D: {
      screen: D,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'D',
      },
    }
  }
)
```

But the title is not being shown on header, it is blank

I have also tried setting title in each screen

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'A'
 }
```

But this is not working,
What I need to change to make it working,

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a function to navigation options.

```
    const drNav = createDrawerNavigator(
      {

        A: {
          screen: A,
          navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'A',
          }),
        },
```

You can find futher information on the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#routeconfigs).